# CoreData entity with Boolean attribute being saved as an NSNumber object

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Wondering if anyone else had come across this, or if there's a reason and I'm doing something wrong.

I have an app with CoreData. In the schema I have a 'content' entity with an 'unlocked' attribute which is set to Boolean.

However when I save out the Obj C class for the entity though Xcode, unlocked appears within content.h as:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * unlocked;
```

If I change it to Boolean in content.h, I get an ARC compiling error. However if I leave it as an NSNumber object when I try and fetch it, it's coming back inconsistently (as in if I have an NSLog printing it, it comes back as a different value each time I run).

I can figure out a fairly obvious work-around, setting unlocked as an NSString to 'yes' or 'no' and compare that at the relevant point, but I wanted to know if anyone knew why this was happening or if there is way to keep it as a Boolean.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can  choose the option *"Use scalar properties for primitive data types"* when creating the managed object subclasses in Xcode, then you will get `@property (nonatomic) BOOL unlocked;`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

CoreData stores objects, which BOOL is not.

`[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]`

Is the way to set the attribute and you can use it by reading mybool = [content.unlocked boolValue];

Comment: You can also use literal syntax to set boolean Core Data attributes:
`object.boolAttribute = @YES`
`object.boolAttribute = @NO`

Comment: Cheers for the explanation. `[content.unlocked boolValue]` got it working.

Answer (score 2):

BOOLs are stored like `NSNumbers` in Core Data (if you look at your sqlite tables, you'll see they're stored as integers.  So, you convert the `BOOL` to `NSNumber` before storing and convert the `NSNumber` to `BOOL` (or just us it as-is 0/1) when retrieving.

I've not seen any inconsistency, however -- if the stored `NSNumber` is zero, it is equivalent to `NO` and if nonzero, it is `YES`.

Comment: Think I was casting it incorrectly after fetching it, which was causing the inconsistency. Cheers for the help.